# Why does R strip names of vector extracted from a one-column matrix with named rows?

Tags: r, vector, names

I want to take one row of matrix `M` and treat the row as a named vector, with the column names of the original matrix as the names of the vector. Usually `M[x, ]` does what I want but this fails if:
(a) the rows of the matrix are named, and
(b) the number of columns is 1.

I can work around this, but it seems inelegant. What is the purpose of this behaviour (and in particular why does it make any difference that the rows are named)?

Examples:

```
M <- structure(c(72L, 92L, 81L, 81L, 87L, 76L, 89L, 70L, 70L, 73L, 
74L, 75L), .Dim = 4:3, .Dimnames = list(c("SeptQuiz", "Midterm", 
"NovQuiz", "Final"), c("Anne", "Bo", "Cameron"))) # multiple columns, rows are named

(v1 <- M[3, ]) # subsetting one row, as a vector, preserves student names

M <- structure(c(91L, 87L, 83L, 81L), .Dim = c(4L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "Frank")) # one column, rows are unnamed

(v1 <- M[3, ]) # again, subsetting one row as a vector preserves student name

M <- structure(c(91L, 87L, 83L, 81L), .Dim = c(4L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("SeptQuiz", "Midterm", "NovQuiz", "Final"), "Frank")) # one column, rows are named

(v1 <- M[3, ]) # subsetting one row deletes student name

if(ncol(M) == 1 && !is.null(rownames(M))) {names(v1) <- colnames(M)} # kludge to restore student name if it was stripped
```

Comment: @RonakShah No, if I use `drop = FALSE` I get a 1x1 matrix, which is not what I want.

Comment: `?drop` may suggest that a name in fact should be picked also for a length 1 vector: "Any accompanying `dimnames` attribute is adjusted and returned with `x`: if the result is a vector the names are taken from the `dimnames` (if any). **If the result is a length-one vector, the names are taken from the _first_ dimension with a dimname.**"

Comment: Henrik, thanks for pointing out the bolded quote from `?drop`. It certainly doesn't behave like that even when I call the `drop` function explicitly: `MM <- matrix(pi, 1, 1, dimnames=list("xyz", "ABC")); 
vv <- drop(MM); 
str(vv)`

Comment: Although the behavior may conflict with the help text, I think it's fair to drop the name attribute of a length 1 vector - choosing which one of the two dimnames to use  seems completely arbitrary. Just my 2c.

Comment: @Henrik I understand why you say it's arbitrary to choose between the row-name and column-name for a subsetted length-one vector, but in my application I am specifying a row, with an empty column-index (i.e. `M[3, ]`): to me it seems natural here that the column-name should be preserved. For more context: it arises in a function that gets executed millions of times, where M usually has many columns. I don't like that I have to check every time whether `v` is length one and therefore needs its name restored. And apart from that, should it be reported as a bug since it conflicts with `?drop`?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide even more context: you have commented several times that you don't want to use `drop = FALSE`, but I don't understand why. What prevents you from using matrices? A matrix is just a vector with a dim attribute. Can you please elaborate.Cheers

Comment: @Henrik, I guess you're right, I could use `drop=FALSE` to always get a 1 x n matrix with the same row-name and column names as the original matrix. I wouldn't have to change any of my other code because if my existing code addresses `v[k]` (for example) it will still function equivalently if `v` is a 1 x n matrix, I'm not required to change it to `v[1, k]`. Is that correct? Efficiency is a big concern, but I know how to use microbenchmark to see whether this solution is faster than testing every time for n=1. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Henrik my code uses the outer product function. I take `v1` and `v2` from the "tallies" row of matrices `M1` and `M2`, and then calculate a matrix of combined weights `MW <- (v1/sum(v1)) %o% (v2/sum(v2))`. With `v1` and `v2` as vectors, this comes out nicely with the row- and col-names of `MW` corresponding to the colnames of `M1` and `M2`. (Although I need an extra line to deal with the rare case where `v1` or `v2` has length one.) But if I use `drop=FALSE` so `v1` and `v2` are 1 x n matrices (rather than vectors), then the outer product `MW` has dims 1 x m x 1 x n instead of m x n.